# How can I add a Stream Analytics table storage output?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-suite

I am following [this Azure IoT tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-c-huzzah-getstartedkit/#section2.4). One of the last steps in Azure is [creating a Stream Analytics job](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-c-huzzah-getstartedkit/#section2.7) with an output to table storage. Following the tutorial, the first Stream Analytics job output can't be created.

Clicking the "Create" button on the "New output" blade only sends a request to ensure the uniqueness of the **Output alias** and the validity of the **Storage account key**. Nothing else happens.

[image: Attempting to create a new output fails although all input fields are valid]

As you can see in the screenshot, both are valid, but no attempt is made to actually create the output. No error messages are displayed. No Javascript errors are on the page. What on earth must I do to actually create the output, since the "Create" button clearly doesn't?

Comment: I don't think the create button is unavailable. Please check the notification on Azure portal which is a bell icon like this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D8mj.png) shown, and see what happended when creating an output for your stream analytics job. Maybe you just need to wait some moment, or try to refresh your portal page to do the create operation again.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT You're absolutely right - the Create button is quite available and clickable. No new alerts show up on the bell icon when I click the Create button. Nothing at all changes when I click the Create button. It only makes one HTTP request, and that literally just validates the storage account key and uniqueness of the output alias, as I noted.

Comment: Do you still see this issue? Once you click the create button, it should have created an output. If you navigate to Outputs page, the output you created should be visible.

Comment: @VigneshChandramohan I've moved on.